# iPhone Facebook Messanger - How does it know who I am?

Tags: iphone, facebook

When installing Facebook Messanger app for iPhone, it automatically knows who I am and says: "Logged in as: xxxxx", continue?
How do they know that? An iPhone app shouldn't be able to access another app... 
Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keychain data can be shared between applications from the same organisation. More info in this SO question:
[How to share keychain data between iOS applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115744/how-to-share-keychain-data-between-ios-applications)

Answer (score 1):

They probably share the same credentials storage group in the Keychain through `keychain-access-group`. It doesn't access the files of the Facebook App but rather the shared keychain.

No other app is part of the shared Keychain group however so a third party app can not access your Facebook details. To access and modify the credentials stored in the keychain, the group of apps need to have the same Bundle Seed ID and the Bundle Seed ID's are unique to a specific Developer Account so a third party developer can not generate the Bundle Seed ID which is the same as the Facebook group of Apps. That means it can not access the data stored in Facebook's Keychain

Some more information is available here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/3/keychain-group-access.html