# How to share data between applications in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I have created one app. It is an update of another application. I have to use the data of first application when launching the second application. How can I accomplish this? My database files are with the same names.

Answer (score 3):

iPhone apps are sandboxed. You can't access any other app's documents folder. Not even your own ones. You can share keychains between your apps or you can open other apps with an argument or a document. That's about it.

Comment: but i am having common database for both of them

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the aforementioned keychain sharing:
[How to share keychain data between iOS applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115744/how-to-share-keychain-data-between-ios-applications)
, if you involved a server, you could use the server as a mediator to exchange information between the two sandboxes.

It is also possible to have one application send another file to another application (although this results in a copy from one sandbox to the other) via registered mime types:
[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

You can also share information via URL handlers.
http://mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/