# How to send get data between ios apps without launching

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to use an ios application like proxy. There will be various application installed on same device and all applications will communicate with server via proxy application.

I will send request to proxy application, Proxy application will handle request, send it to servers and send response to the various applications.

When I use **URLScheme** this will launch application and bringd it front. I dont want applciation launch.Is it possible to make this? Use an application lie a service?

Comment: Good luck getting this passed apple store team if there is a way.

Comment: I willl use enterprise licence- ad hoc distribution. So, no apple no store.

Comment: @aslana In this case, you can can use private APIs, right?

Comment: Yes I can use if there is no solution for this case. Puprpose of project is "mobile single sign on" for other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sign-in across many apps, you should be using the KeychainManager and a shared sub-domain with an entitlement linking the apps together with a keychain-access-group.

See [How to share keychain data between iOS applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115744/how-to-share-keychain-data-between-ios-applications)

Answer (score 1):

The AppSupport framework exposes an Objective-C class suited for interprocess communication: `CPDistributedMessagingCenter`. You can read about its usage and details about how it is implemented [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CPDistributedMessagingCenter).