# Why SSKeychain returns different result with the same parameters for different iOS apps

Tags: ios, uuid, sskeychain

I tried to use SSKeychain to reserve UUID on iOS

and the sample code is below

```
NSString *retrieveuuid = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"tempApp" account:@"tempUser"];
if (retrieveuuid == nil) {
    //Generate UUID
    CFUUIDRef cfuud = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    NSString *uuid = CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfuuid));
    //save in keychain
    [SSKeychain setPassword:uuid forService:@"tempApp" account:@"tempUser"];
    return uuid;
} else {
    return retrieveuuid;
}
```

My question is that I run the first app and then generate a UUID, and then run the second app which
has the same parameters, so that the retrieveduuid should not be null, then why the second App returns a different UUID? I think that will return the same
UUID as first app because I have saved the UUID in the keychain in App1 and try to retrieve it by the same parameters in App2.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UUID is a Universally Unique IdenTifier. Would be kind of stupid if you got the same in two different apps, wouldn't it? ;)

If you want to share keychains between apps, see this question: [How to share keychain data between iOS applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115744/how-to-share-keychain-data-between-ios-applications)

Comment: yeah, I know UUID should be different, just wonder why app2 not retrieves app1's UUID because app1 has saved its UUID into keychain and app2 use the same value of parameters.

Comment: Because apps have sandboxed keychains, just like the filesystem. App 1 can't access the files saved by App 2. The link provides some info about how to share a keychain.