# Is iOS Keychain data sandboxed?

Tags: ios, security, sandbox, keychain

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html), it is. But I've tried the following:

App A stores item in keychain.
App B tries to retrieve same item from keychain. Fails.

Without success. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115744/how-to-share-keychain-data-between-ios-applications

Answer (score 0):

The document you linked to states the following:

> The keychain is intended for storing small amounts of sensitive data *that are specific to your app*. It is not intended as a general-purpose mechanism for encrypting and storing data.

This is unrelated to sandboxing.

Comment: Please, see at the end of the document: `Keychain data for an app is stored outside of the app’s sandbox.`