# share data between 2 application in iPhone

Tags: ios

I want to share userid and password to other application and vice versa in iPhone.

**Scenario:**
I have 2 application in my iPhone,Master application and Child application.I am done with login with master application and its successfully done.Now if I open with child application then automatically user can login with master application and same as vice versa.

It means ,I want to share data between 2 application in iPhone.

is it possible in iPhone? Does anyone has done similar or anyone has any suggestion please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: child application is extension ?

Comment: No its just like 2 separate appplication

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115744/how-to-share-keychain-data-between-ios-applications) out.

Comment: custom url scheme is what I would prefer in this case...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following ways to share data between two applications.

1. UIDocumentationInteractionController
2. iCloud API
3. Shared KeyChain Access
4. UIActivityController
5. Web Services
6. Custom URL Scheme
7. App Groups

You can use the following link to share applications in two iPhone applications :-

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios8-app-groups

http://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/

Comment: Nothing in your list has anything to do with any specific version of Xcode. Most are features of iOS that have been around for years.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need to go from following links & need to play with `Shared KeyChain Access` & `Custom URL Scheme`.

[Share data between two or more iPhone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications)

http://agostini.tech/2017/08/13/sharing-data-between-applications-and-extensions-using-app-groups/

http://www.enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/